# Load static local pdf file in next.js app

Tags: webpack, next.js

I have a pdf file, which needs to be opened in a new tab, when clicked on the link. I failed to config a webpack file loader, so I did the configuration in next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.pdf$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        } 
      ]
    })
    return config
  },
}
```

The frontend looks as follows

```
import Agb from '../documents/AGB.pdf';

const navigation = {
  legal: [
    { name: 'Impressum', href: 'https://xxxx' },
    { name: 'Datenschutz', href: 'https://xxx' },
    { name: 'AGB', href: {Agb} },
  ],
}

.....

<div className="mt-12 md:mt-0">
   <h3 className="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-400 tracking-wider uppercase">Legal</h3>
    <ul role="list" className="mt-8 space-y-4">
      {navigation.legal.map((item) => (
         <li key={item.name}>
             <a href={item.href} className="text-base text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900" target="_blank">
                {item.name}
             </a>
         </li>
      ))}
   </ul>
```

Clicking on AGB results into 404 page and following link:

```
http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]
```

What am I missing in my config?

Comment: Why you don't just put that file on public ?

Answer (score -1):

You're getting this result because you are passing a pdf object to href but it needs a string.
You have to put the file in the public folder and pass the name with the extension to the href